# What exactly is happening in the piece of code with the newInstance() method being used statically?

Tags: android

I understand mostly everything in this code, except when newIstance() is being used. Could anyone please explain. Much appreciated.

```
public class DateDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

public static String TAG = "DateDialogFragment";

static Context sContext;
static Calendar sDate;
static DateDialogFragmentListener sListener;

public static DateDialogFragment newInstance(Context context, int titleResource, Calendar date){
    DateDialogFragment dialog  = new DateDialogFragment();

sContext = context;
    sDate = date;

Bundle args = new Bundle();
args.putInt("title", titleResource);
dialog.setArguments(args);
return dialog;
   }
}
```

I made an edit, I guess its working differently when its static. I assume thats why I am confused. How is the method changed when its static? I don't really see why not do it in the constructor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using fragments (any class that extends `Fragment`) you frequently need to pass some data. That's achieved by using the `setArguments` method which receives a `Bundle`. Since doing so requires a lot of code (create the bundle, take into account key names, etc.), it is common to pass the data to a static method (usually called `newInstance`). The idea of that method is to create the arguments bundle and pass it to the `Fragment`; then it returns the fragment and you can put it where ever you want.

Another advantage of using fragments that way is that when you are inserting a fragment directly in an XML layout, there must be an empty constructor (or nothing at all). If you create a fragment with a constructor (to pass its necessary data) you could get some errors regarding the missing empty constructor.

Comment: Ahhh, I see. Thank you very much. So you could have accomplished the same thing, but doing it this way is common practice?

Comment: Yes, it is common and recommended.

Comment: I don't get that. Why not use a constructor to pass data? The code shown above over-complicats things.

Comment: @Harald imagine you put the fragment within an XML layout using the `<fragment/>` tag. How would the inflater know what parameters pass to the constructor?